# Docker container keeps on restarting again and again in docker-compose but not when runs isolated

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a python program that uses MongoDB and I want to deploy it on a server, that's because I write a docker-compose file. My problem is that when I run the python project isolated with the **docker build -t PROJET_NAME .** and **docker run image** commands everything works properly, however when executing **docker-compose up -d** the python container restarts over and over again. What am I doing wrong?
I just tried to log it but nothing shows up

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

ENV PROD=true

COPY . .

# Installing requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN export PYTHONPATH=$PATHONPATH:`pwd`
CMD ["python3", "foo.py"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "prod"
      APP_DEBUG: "False"
      MONGODB_DATABASE: db
      MONGODB_USERNAME: appuser
      MONGODB_PASSWORD: mongopassword
      MONGODB_HOSTNAME: mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - internal

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: mongod --auth
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongodbuser
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mongodbrootpassword
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: db
      MONGODB_DATA_DIR: /data/db
      MONDODB_LOG_DIR: /dev/null
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: What do the logs show for the failing container?

Comment: There´s nothing on the logs. I think it´s caused by the restring which happens every few seconds

Comment: You sure there is nothing at all displayed on the terminal? Or when you say `restart`, it means your terminal closes. AFAIK there is always logs of some sorts when using docker-compose.

Comment: What is `foo.py` supposed to do?  If it's exiting immediately in the Compose environment, have you tried instrumenting it (for example, with `print()` calls) to show how far it gets?

Comment: @DavidMaze foo. py is a scraper that uses selenium to get some products, it works fine when running docker build .

Comment: @AvivLo i mean restart when i type ```docker ps -a``` and status of app container is Restarting (0) 3 seconds ago  every time I write the command. When log the docker-compose only get logs of mongo container like this ```mongodb      | {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-03T02:10:22.347+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}```

Comment: In your compose if you comment out APP_ENV and APP_DEBUG, `docker-compose down -v` and `docker-compose up` (without -d), does that make any different?

Comment: In your comment to @DavidMaze what do you mean it works fine with `docker build`? Running it as standalone would be with `docker run`, did you get confused while writing the comment or with using the `build` command?